# how to use openmp in a c++ program

Tags: c++, multithreading, ubuntu, openmp

I would like to use OpenMP to parallelize some of my functions in a c++ program.

I am using ubuntu 12.04, on intel i5 with 4 cores. 
But after following certain steps, I do not see any improve in performance. I could see that only one CPU core is being used. (system monitor in ubuntu )

What I did..

added `#include <omp.h>`

added these two lines before a for loop

`omp_set_num_threads(4);`

`#pragma omp parallel for`

in CMakeLists.txt,

I added `target_link_libraries (executable  -fopenmp -lgomp ${PCL_LIBRARIES} )`

Can you please help me in getting the parallelism ?

Thank you!

Comment: Not every cycle can be parallelized. Show it.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get, what you meant. Not even once, I could see that multiple threads are running in the system monitor. I am wondering there is some  configuration that I might be missing out.

Comment: You should provide the compilation flag "-fopenmp" either through the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS variable or through the [per-target COMPILE_FLAGS property](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2006-July/009992.html). Giving flags through the link libraries is probably not good, I'm not 100% sure, but I don't see how sending compilation flags to the linker's library list is going to work.

Comment: adding `find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")` is giving me an error *** double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00007ff424006b20 ***.....any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Mikael Persson , I removed -fopenmp from the target link libraries and added
`find_package(OpenMP)
if (OPENMP_FOUND)
    set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
endif()`

**This is working.**

The error `r *** double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00007ff424006b20 ***` was arising because in the for loop, i was trying to use `push_back()` function to load a stack and the index was dependant on the for loop index. I think that was the cause of the problem.

I learnt one more thing that one can have nested for loops and OMP can work without errors if their variables are independent and produce valid results